# How to change Android SeekBar track start position?

Tags: android, position, seekbar

I'd like to set the `SeekBars`'s track start position so it does not start from the left side of the seekbar, but form an arbitrary position. Here is a photoshop image how it should look like:

[http://i.imgur.com/QCMEu.png](https://i.imgur.com/QCMEu.png)

It should be just a graphical effect, the `SeekBar`'s underlying logic is not changed.

I tried to change the `Seekbar.getprogressDrawable.SetBounds()` to change the track image position, but no luck.

Answer (score 10):

add this proprety

```
 android:progress="2"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I`d like to set the start position of the track line, not the seeekbar`s thumb. 

As you can see in the  image (http://i.imgur.com/QCMEu.png) the seekbar`s track does not start at the far left of the seekbar, but starts form the first quarter of the seekbar. I`d like to acheve that effect.

Comment: u want arrange seek from middle. or desired position .

Answer (score 8):

You can set progress of SeekBar in xml as:

```
android:progress="10"
android:max="90" <!-- maximum seekbar progress -->
```

you can programmatically set the progress of SeekBar as:

```
seekBar.setProgress(10);
```

Comment: Hi, I`d like to set the start position of the track, not the progress.

Comment: actually i am unable to open the link.can you please upload the same image here in SO so that we can get idea what you want exactly?

Answer (score 3):

May be your problem is similar to [Seekbar for two values [-50, 0, 50]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-5).

Thanks to Commonsware to point to right direction. I wrote a class inspired by code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar) to get the solution.

https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar

Answer (score 1):

By Programatically,we can start the progress and set the maximum of seekbar progress.

```
//start from <starting value>
seekBar.setProgress(<strating_value>);

//Set to maximum Value<max_value>
seekBar.setMax(<max_value>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this:
android:rotation="180"
to the XML and then the seekbar will flip the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem.
That's how I have solved it.

Assume, we need seekbar starting from 10 and ending at 150.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {...
     yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
     yourSpinner.setMax(150 - 10);

     int newProgress;

     yourSpinner.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                newProgress= 10 + progress;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(newProgress), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```