# Seekbar for two values [-50, 0, 50]

Tags: android, seekbar

I need to place "*start point*" in center of seek bar.
How can i do like this?

[image: seek barr for two values]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Thanks to Commonsware to point to right direction. I wrote a class inspired by code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar) to get the solution.

https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar

Comment: This! very nice! I find the thumb a bit to big but that is adjustable of course, also was very easy to change to color to the left and right. Only having difficulty with setting the setNormalizedValue, when set to -1, it starts all the way at the left, when set to 1 it starts all the way at the right. can't get it to set centered

Comment: solution: value between 0 and 1, where 0.5 is the center.

Comment: Is it available to set this custom seek bar to be vertical?

Comment: Do you have a working version of this seekbar in vertical orientation?

Answer (score 6):

[image: customSeekBar]

As Above all said, it can be achieved my implementing our own custom seekbar.

I tried in the following way and it worked out for me.

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" 
  android:layout_margin="20dp">

 <com.example.customseekbar.CustomSeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.customseekbar;

import com.example.suricustomseekbar.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SeekBar mseekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mseekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
    mseekBar.setProgress(50);
     }
  }
```

**CustomSeekBar.java**

```
package com.example.customseekbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

  public class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar {

private Rect rect;
private Paint paint ;
private int seekbar_height; 

public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    rect = new Rect();
    paint = new Paint();
    seekbar_height = 6;
}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    rect.set(0 + getThumbOffset(), 
            (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height/2), 
            getWidth()- getThumbOffset(), 
            (getHeight() / 2) + (seekbar_height/2));

    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);



    if (this.getProgress() > 50) {


        rect.set(getWidth() / 2,
                (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height/2), 
                getWidth() / 2 + (getWidth() / 100) * (getProgress() - 50),
                getHeight() / 2 + (seekbar_height/2));

        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

    }

    if (this.getProgress() < 50) {

        rect.set(getWidth() / 2 - ((getWidth() / 100) * (50 - getProgress())),
                (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height/2),
                 getWidth() / 2,
                 getHeight() / 2 + (seekbar_height/2));

        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: This custom class must not call **super.onDraw(canvas);**
This will cause draw original SeekBar

And you should add code draw thumb

Comment: What modifications are needed to make this vertical?

Answer (score 2):

To start in the middle, you can call `setProgress()` with a value that is half of your total range.

To have the `SeekBar` start in the middle and go to an end (i.e., your blue line runs from middle to the left or from middle to the right), you would need to create your own replacement for `SeekBar`, or find somebody else who has done this, as this is not supported by `SeekBar` itself.

Comment: `own replacement for SeekBar`, you meen `style`?

Comment: @lysenkobv: No, I mean a Java class. `SeekBar`, like the `ProgressBar` from which it inherits, is designed to put the starting point of the bar at the left edge. I will be rather surprised if that can be changed via a style. I expect that you will need to create your own `View` that handles this. For example, `RangeSeekBar` (https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) was implemented as a subclass of `ImageView`, to handle the case where you want two thumbs instead of one.

Answer (score -1):

I just made this by Kotlin, perhaps someone likes it.
[check this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuCAS.gif)

**First:** Create class with any name to customize seek bar like this:

```
class CustomSeekBar(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : AppCompatSeekBar(context, attrs) {

    private var rect: Rect = Rect()
    private var paint: Paint = Paint()
    private var seekbarHeight: Int = 6

    @Synchronized
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        // for seek bar line
        rect[0, height / 2 - seekbarHeight / 2, width] = height / 2 + seekbarHeight / 2
        paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_30)
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)

        //for right side
        if (this.progress > 0) {
            rect[width / 2, height / 2 - seekbarHeight / 2, width / 2 + width / 200 * (progress)] =
                height / 2 + seekbarHeight / 2

            paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)
        }

        //for left side
        if (this.progress < 0) {
            rect[width / 2 - width / 200 * (-progress), height / 2 - seekbarHeight / 2, width / 2] =
                height / 2 + seekbarHeight / 2

            paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

**Second** Go to the xml and put this tag

```
 <com.YOUR_PACKAGE.CustomSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_habit_point"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:max="100"
        android:min="-100"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_small
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_custom_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_seek_bar_point"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_point_part"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_point_part"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
```

and that is.

Comment: Waste of time. Not working.

Comment: please give me more details to understand why is not working.