# SeekBar thumb at the middle of progress not at the starting point

Tags: android, seekbar

How can I center the thumb of SeekBar so that If I scroll left it gives negative value and if I scroll right it gives me positive value??

Comment: What about the progress fill? What is your requirement for the progress? Should it be started from center always?

Comment: there should be no progress fill, thumb should be at center always so that scrolling to left gives negative value and to right gives positive value

Comment: go through this link...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50/23324198#23324198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this would help.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:progress="50"
        android:max="100" />
```

And use `int progress = mSeekBar1.getProgress()-50;` to get the progress.

Comment: how to remove progress fill till 50?

Comment: android:progressDrawable="@android:color/background_dark" should do it. You may use your own drawable instead of this.

Comment: I want my minimum value to be 50 and maximum value to be 150. Setting maximum was straightforward but minimum is not setting whatsoever. Can you help me regarding that? Thanks!

Comment: friend I want show -95 to +95.because the signal strength between this value.can you tell how to show this?