# SeekBar ascending and descending

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

Is it possible to make a SeekBar in Android with a descending value when I go left and ascending value when I go right?

My idea is to have a SeekBar from 0 to 100. It will start in the middle at 50.

So far, I had no problem.

But I want to subtract the value with the SeekBar when the progress is descending and to add the value when the progress is ascending.

Can you tell me if this is possible with the standard android Seekbar?

Comment: I think you mean [something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50), in which case you need to make your own custom view, or use one made by a third party. Such as the one from that link.

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you asking, but with some basic math you can make your SeekBar to return negative or positive values. Also, you can deduct the direction by extracting the previous position from the current position of the SeekBar.

Comment: I have 3 Seekbars with different values and with this forth seekbar I want to change the values of all seekbars.   So when I go right I want that all 3 seekbars will ascend. And when I go left descend.