# Android Seekbar starting point

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

The range of my seekbar is between (-100,100) and the thumb starts on 0 (in the middle of the seekbar). 
I want to the progress tint starts at middle.
With this library, the progress tint starts always in the beginning of the seekbar.

I used this library, with the ticks.
https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar

[image]

My xml.

[image]

And my kotlin code:

```
mBinding.seekbarWorkout.customSectionTrackColor { colorIntArr ->
            for (i in 0..9) {
                colorIntArr[i] = resources.getColor(R.color.white_transparent, null)
            }

            true //true if apply color , otherwise no change
        }

mBinding.seekbarWorkout.onSeekChangeListener = object : OnSeekChangeListener {
            override fun onSeeking(seekParams: SeekParams?) {}

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: IndicatorSeekBar?) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: IndicatorSeekBar?) {
                updateViewModel()
            }
        }
```

The track progress color must starts in the middle of the seekbar.
I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post library dependency or link which use for seekbar

Comment: There is one property for  .progress(53) u can set value in Java file.

Comment: How can you paste an example please?

Comment: you have issue with the progress tint starts always in the beginning of the seekbar. So i can review library and try to solve issue

Comment: can you please?

Comment: I have said Already you can set value in Java file also in Xml file which you want, indicatorSeekBar.setProgress(0);

Comment: I've done this. but the problem is, progress always starts at the beginning

Comment: Can you post your xml file and also Java file code so i can elaborate more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205228/discussion-between-hernani-pereira-and-arti).

Comment: Might be this is help you https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar

Comment: the only way is doing this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50/23324198#23324198][1]

Answer (score 0):

Tried in demo and working fine.

```
    <com.warkiz.widget.IndicatorSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isb_progress="0" // this property is your solution
        app:isb_min="-100"
        app:isb_max="100"
        app:isb_tick_marks_size="3dp"
        app:isb_ticks_count="5" />
```

For me this code worked fine if its still not working then rather then implementing library and copy that IndicatorSeekBar class to understand it better.

Comment: the color starts at the beginning of the seekbar

Comment: is example demo i have't found this issue.

Comment: The progress color should start in the middle of the seekbar, and in this library it starts in the beginning of the range

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do that.
The only way to do this:

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50/23324198#23324198)