# SeekBar which progresses in two direction

Tags: android, android-progressbar, seekbar

I am making an Android app which needs seekbar with single thumb and able to fill in both positive and negative direction.[When progress is negative seekbar looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keKqW.jpg) [And for positive progress something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygpu9.jpg)

I searched over internet and saw many custom seekbars but none of all resembled this.
Can anyone please suggest how to implement this seekbar

Comment: Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50

Comment: God bless you @VivekThummar